# sublime text 3 Ctrl+B can't compile tex file

Tags: sublime-text, latextools

My configuration:

1. Sublime Text 3, **3143**;
2. Installed **MacTex**;
3. Installed **LatexTools**, and set "builder" to "basic".

I press Ctrl+B and get

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

how to solve this problem

Comment: Can you verify that in the menu *Tools > Build System* you have selected *Automatic*, because this looks like it uses the wrong build system.

Comment: Thank you for reminding. After changing build system to latex, it compiled. But if I change this config manually, I need set it manually everytime when I compile different type files, such as cpp...

Comment: If you select *Automatic* it should always use the correct build system and LaTeXTools builder inside LaTeX files. Do you have the correct syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got it.

Maybe for **Sublime Text 3143**, we need click *Tools > Build With...*, then choose *XeLatex* for the first time you using this compiler after updating **Sublime Text 3**. And it will automatically compile tex with XeLatex forever.